# Alternative to Simplenews, or a way to send formatted mailing lists to subscribers?

Tags: emails

I have installed simplenews on Drupal 7 but it seems all the related modules: Simplenews Content Selection (to build up the newsletter using nodes or views) and Simplenews Template are outdated (Drupal6).

Is there another way to use the nodes in the sites or at least creating a template to reuse with this module?

Or is there a way using other mailing list modules or custom code to build up newsletters from nodes?

br. onirio

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new [Newsletter module](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter).

```
Features

Multiple newsletters lists configurable on terms, not vocabularies
Plain text or HTML out of the box
Multiple schedules Each newsletter can have more than one schedule, e.g. Daily, Monthly, Weekly, manually or even custom, eg after 10 new posts for this term.
Centralized administration and configuration on single page.
Users can customize the terms in the list they subscribe to
Custom template per list
Statistics (CTR and Open-Rate)
Drupal 7 only
```

Comment: As far as you know, does Newsletter module supports the the newsletter build up using nodes or views abd views?

Comment: I have only kicked the tires on it and haven't dug deep. I know it's highly configurable though. It's worth a look.

Comment: I tried Newsletter but it seems it cannot save the newsletters only their template.

Comment: I know the module is getting a lot of development attention right now and the maintainer is currently very responsive to feedback, I would put in a support/feature request and see what you get back.

Answer (score 0):

This method (or something similar) worked in D6, I guess you can still do it in D7: Add a [reference field](http://drupal.org/project/references) to your newsletter, load the referenced nodes in the preprocess function for your template using [node_load_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7), and render them using as a list of teasers using [node_view_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7).

Another approach would be to build a view and attach it to a newsletter node using [Entity View Attachment](http://drupal.org/project/eva). However that's just a thought - I haven't tried the combination of Simplenews and EVA myself.

Comment: I think I managed to attached a view to my content/content type using either Viewsfield module or 1 line of code: print views_embed_view('myViewName'), I can see the view in the preview but I receive a blank email.

Comment: If you add a field, make sure it's visible on the "manage display" page for the "newsletter" view mode (probably `/admin/structure/types/manage/simplenews/display/teaser`). If you add code directly to the template, make sure you're overriding the right template (I think it is `simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php`).

Comment: That is the problem: when using views insertions in newsletter the newsletter content won't pass through the simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php template.